# Differences between DFD (Data Flow Diagram) and Class Diagram?

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I need to know this differences in order to undestand how to use them right.

Which are the differences of DFD (Data Flow Diagram) and Class diagram ?And,
Which are the best diagram to build a software?

Thank you..

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort." Additionally, _best diagram_ is asking for an opinion, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A DFD is one behavioral view of a system while a class diagram is a pure static one. A class diagram shows classes with attributes/operations and how they are connected. A DFD shows how data "flow" (i.e. class instances and/or plain objects are interchanged) under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of diagram to choose depends on the objective.

DFD (Data Flow Diagram) is a graphical mapping of data structures and their interrelationships (storage, external sources, etc).

In turn the class diagram shows the entities, objects and their relationships.

I recommend first mastering the creation of class diagrams when building software.